# Are neo4j OR queries slower than AND queries?

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j and an experimenting with storing user information in it. I am creating nodes called *Person* in which I store simple attributes like *username*, *preferredLanguage* etc. For complex attributes like *address*, *phone* etc, I am using separate nodes. Following is an example:

```
CREATE (m1:email { value: 'user1@company.com', type: 'work', primary: true })
CREATE (m2:email { value: 'user1@gmail.com', type: 'home' })
CREATE (m3:email { value: 'user1@yahoo.com', type: 'home' })
CREATE (ph1:phone { value: '1111111111', type: 'mobile' })
CREATE (ph2:phone { value: '2222222222', type: 'work' })
CREATE (p:Person { username: 'user1', phone: preferredLanguage: 'English'})
CREATE (p) - [: email] -> (m1)
CREATE (p) - [: email] -> (m2)
CREATE (p) - [: email] -> (m3)
CREATE (p) - [: phone] -> (ph1)
CREATE (p) - [: phone] -> (ph2)
```

I have created a million users like this and indexed all the attributes of all types of nodes. I am trying out different types of searches on this data.
Consider the following query:

```
MATCH (p: Person) - [: phone] -> (ph: phone)
MATCH (p) - [: email] -> (e: email)
WHERE e.value = 'user1@gmail.com' AND ph.value = '1111111111'
RETURN DISTINCT p.username
```

This completes very fast - in about 100ms. It returns 1 user.

Now consider the following query:

```
MATCH (p: Person) - [: phone] -> (ph: phone)
MATCH (p) - [: email] -> (e: email)
WHERE e.value = 'user1@gmail.com' OR ph.value = '3333333333'
RETURN DISTINCT p.username
```

This query takes about 6s to complete and returns two users. How can I make this faster ?

Comment: Do you have any indexes? Specifically on `email.value` and `phone.value`?

Comment: Oh, yes you do: _"I have created a million users like this and indexed all the attributes of all types of nodes."_

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MATCH (ph) WHERE (ph:phone OR ph:email) AND (ph.value = '3333333333' 
OR ph.value = 'user1@gmail.com')
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE (p)-[:phone]->(ph) OR (p)-[:email]->(ph) 
RETURN DISTINCT p.username
```

Here, we first obtain the necessary `phone` and `email` nodes, and then the `person` node, linked with either one of those.

You can simplify your query a bit as well, like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:phone]->(ph)
MATCH (p)-[:email]->(e)
WHERE e.value = 'user1@gmail.com' OR ph.value = '3333333333'
RETURN DISTINCT p.username
```

Comment: I think the variable name 'ph' and 'e' don't exist beyond the WHERE statement. This query is not terminating at all in my system (there are a million users). I think it is executing the second MATCH independently without using the result of the first MATCH.

Comment: ohkk, let me retry

Comment: updated, try now

Comment: It took 9s with this query :(

Comment: Yeah, multiple `OR` operations here

Comment: Try the second query, it might not bring major change, but I think that's the best, that can happen, since we are going over all the user nodes